# preg_match for partial matches

Tags: php, preg-match

How do I use preg_match for partial matches?

When I have the string:

```
www.stackoverflow.com
```

and when I enter

```
stackoverflow.com or stackoverflow
```

to match the phrase it returns false. How do I make it work for partial matches?

Comment: You question is not very clear (atleast to me). what is that you are trying to match? what regex are you currently using?

Comment: The way you've described it you could use `www.stackoverflow.com` as haystack and `stackoverflow.com` as needle in strpos()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`preg_match`](https://www.php.net/preg_match) uses [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expressions), which you can get a very good tutorial for [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).

In your specific case, you are looking for a string, followed by an optional segment (to change your search into English, you want to find "stackoverflow", optionally followed by ".com"). Sections of regular expressions can be made [optional](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) by using the `?` modifier:

```
preg_match('/stackoverflow(\.com)?/', $your_string)
```

The regular expression here (`/stackoverflow(\.com)?/`) says the same thing as our English version above -- match "stackoverflow" followed by an optional ".com".

Here's a quick overview of how the regex works:

- The slash on each end of the pattern is a [delimiter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) which PHP uses to enclose regular expressions.
- The majority of characters in regular expressions are matched literally, so `stackoverflow` matches "stackoverflow"
- The parentheses define a [group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), which is made optional by the `?`. Without the group, only the token directly before the `?` would be made optional (in this case the "m").
- Note that there is a slash before the dot in ".com". This is because [dots](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) are special characters in regular expressions (used kind of like a wildcard), so it needs to be escaped if you want to match a *literal* dot.

Answer (score 1):

`preg_match` is not anchored by default so it will find partial matches without any special effort. Do you have the arguments in the correct order? It's the regex first, then the string to be searched. So:

```
if (preg_match('/stackoverflow/', 'www.stackoverflow.com')) {
    ...
}
```